# Array don't take all the space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use twitter bootstrap 3

I have an table

```
<table id="hospitalTable" data-show-header="true" class="table table-striped" data-toggle="table" data-height="250">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/301/

column don't use all the space available.

Is there a possiblity to use all the space

Comment: If jsfiddle marked some of the elements in your code in red that means something is wrong, check your markup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because your table head has three columns and your body has 4. The 4th on the body is pushing the content. Place another empty `th` in your `thead` or add a `colspan="2"` on the last `th` that should fix the issue. You also might want to make the last td have a width so it doesn't fill the space.

http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/303/